# python tkinter append list

Tags: python, list, tkinter, append

I am an amateur python programer with 2 months of experience.  I am trying to write a GUI to-do list through tkinter.  The actual placement of the buttons are not important. I can play around with those after.  I need some help with displaying the appended item to the list.  In the program, it updates well on the digit, but it won't print onto the list.  I double checked it on the console and it says "tkinter.StringVar object at 0x102fa4048" but didn't update the actual list.  What I need help is how can I update the list Main_Q on my the label column?  Much appreciate some direction and coding help. Thanks.

```
Main_Q =["read","clean dishes", "wash car"]


from tkinter import*
root=Tk(className="total tasks in the Q")


#formula

def update():
global Main_Q
a=len(Main_Q)
num.set(a)

def add2list():
Main_Q.append(name)
a=len(Main_Q)
num.set(a)
print (Main_Q)


#output

num=StringVar()
y=Label(root, textvariable=num).grid(row=0, column=1)

#input

name=StringVar()
b=Entry(root, textvariable=name).grid(row=7,column=0)


#buttons
z=Button(root, text="update", command=update).grid(row=7, column=2)
add2list=Button(root,text="add", command=add2list).grid(row=7,         
column=1)


r = 0
for c in Main_Q:
Label(text=c, relief=RIDGE,width=15).grid(row=r,column=0)
r = r + 1

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your for loop which build up your labels doesnt get called after each time you have entered a new "task". To easily fix this you can move this loop into your update function.

If you want to prevent of looping through widget everytime you can create a new list with all widgets which already have been created:

```
createdWidgets = []
widgetsQueue = []
```

In your update function you than have to iterate through the `widgetsQueue` (widgetsQueue.pop() for instance), create the widgets and append the widget to the `createdWidgetes` list.

```
def update():
    global Main_Q
    r = 0
    for c in Main_Q:
        Label(text=c, relief=RIDGE,width=15).grid(row=r,column=0)
        r += 1 # shorthand for r = r + 1
```

**Some addition notes:**

1. for the entry it is easier to seperate the definition and placement:

   ```
   b = Entry(root)
   b.grid(row=7,column=0)
   ```

   because than Entry() returns its instance and you can use it to get the text:

   ```
   b.get()
   ```
2. if you go shopping do you throw everything into one bag ?

   ```
   from tkinter import *
   ```

   does axactly that(in this case the globals() variable would be the bag).If you want to read more about that [Importing Python Modules](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm). To prevent that and shorten the amount of letters to type:

   ```
   import tkinter as t # or tk 
   root = t.Tk()
   ```

*But for sure, if you just want a small program its okay.

Comment: Good afternoon Sense4.  Thanks for the comments and the direction.  I did what you asked me to do, which is to put the for loop into the "update" button.  It's updating now on the for loop, but it still not printing what I typed in.  For example, if I type in "shower", It's printing  "PY_VAR1".  And in the IDLE it's printing <tkinter.StringVar object at 0x102fc6f60>".  Thanks again.  After this this is figured out, I would begin to learn how to use the "destroy" feature and the Return button to update.   I will "struggle" those on my own first to see if I can figure it out.  :)

Comment: Hey, for that you should take a look onto my addition notes. I dont know if its also possible with a stringVar but I always use the method I have mentioned there for an Entry. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

## Design:

To resolve your problem, you need to design this simple solution:

1. retrieve the text of the `Tkinter.Entry` widget using [`get()`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/entry.html) method.
2. add the text you got in *1* to `Main_Q` using [`append()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) method.
3. bind the button that updates on click both  `Main_Q` and your GUI using [`command`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/button.html) method.
4. create a new Tkinter.Label widget, set its text to the value you got in 1 and increment its corresponding row in the GUI.

I prefer to organize your code within a class that contains a constructor where `Main_Q` is initialized so that we call `initialize_user_interface()` to initialize the GUI with its three elements:

```
    def __init__(self, parent):
            Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
            self.parent = parent
            self.Main_Q = ["read", "clean dishes", "wash car"]
            self.r = 0 # position of the row of each label
            self.initialize_user_interface()
```

The method `initialize_user_interface()` does what its name says. We mainly bind the function `update_gui()` that inserts a new label with the text set to what the user types in `Tkinter.Entry` widget using `command = self.update_gui`

```
ef initialize_user_interface(self):
        self.parent.title("Update GUI")
        self.parent.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.parent.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        for e in self.Main_Q:
            Tkinter.Label(self.parent, anchor = Tkinter.W, text = e).grid(row = self.r, sticky = Tkinter.W)
            self.r+=1
        self.entry_text = Tkinter.Entry(self.parent)
        self.entry_text.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        self.button_update = Tkinter.Button(self.parent, text = "Update", command = self.update_gui).grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = Tkinter.E)
```

Finally, nothing is simpler than `update_gui()` function:

```
def update_gui(self):
        self.r+=1 # increment the row reserved to the new label
        self.Main_Q.append(self.entry_text.get())
        Tkinter.Label(self.parent, anchor = Tkinter.W, text = self.entry_text.get()).grid(row = self.r, sticky = Tkinter.W)
```

## Programming the application:

Here is the full program:

```
'''
Created on Mar 11, 2016

@author: Bill BEGUERADJ
'''
import Tkinter


class Begueradj(Tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.main_queue = ["read", "clean dishes", "wash car"]
        self.r = 0
        self.initialize_user_interface()


    def initialize_user_interface(self):
        self.parent.title("Update GUI")
        self.parent.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.parent.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        for e in self.main_queue:
            Tkinter.Label(self.parent, anchor = Tkinter.W, text = e).grid(row = self.r, sticky = Tkinter.W)
            self.r+=1
        self.entry_text = Tkinter.Entry(self.parent)
        self.entry_text.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        self.button_update = Tkinter.Button(self.parent, text = "Update", command = self.update_gui).grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = Tkinter.E)

    def update_gui(self):
        self.r+=1
        self.main_queue.append(self.entry_text.get())
        Tkinter.Label(self.parent, anchor = Tkinter.W, text = self.entry_text.get()).grid(row = self.r, sticky = Tkinter.W)


def main():
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    b = Begueradj(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

## Demo:

Here is a screenshot of the running program:

[image]

## Note:

I coded the previous program using Python 2.7, so if you want to test it, please change `Tkinter` to `tkinter`. Everything else remains the same.

Comment: Hi Bil, thanks very much for the help.  I would never thought about write it like this.  I kinda understand the class concept, but not 100% clear.  This example helps quite a bit.  I would like to add more feature to this small exercise to further my learning.  Thanks again, for now.

Comment: You are welcome. If you do not understand something with my code, please do not hesitate to ask me any time. @fishtang

Comment: Hi Bill,  Would you so kind explain to me why two init statements? thanks.  I seen some codes with only one init statement and some with 2.  class Begueradj(Tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

Comment: A class can have not only one or two `__init__()` but more and as much as you want/need. That is called a [`constructor`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_%28object-oriented_programming%29). Please take time to read about and understand the [object oriented concepts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming). When you finish, I will explain you the rest of your question. @fishtang

Comment: Bill, I read the article as you recommended.  This is how I understand the 2 init statement. 1st, you have a root window, and then right away we created a frame class. The 1st init statement is to make existence of the class frame. The second init statement is the actually instance of a frame. This is a simple as I can make sense of it. The way I understand OOP is like 3x5 cards.  The fact that there is a card is like the 1st init statement. and as we write a name or a thing on the 1st card to create the first instance of whatever we want in the class is the second statement.  @BILL BEGUERADJ